# Usa calculate Tolls cost using here maps

Tags: here-api

Using this example https://developer.here.com/documentation/toll-cost/topics/example-tollcost.html
and description from here https://developer.here.com/documentation/toll-cost/topics/resource-tollcost-input-interface.html trying to calculate tolls on usa roads
First found paid road to be sure to have it on the route - found here https://www.sixt.com/toll-roads/usa/ - rout in Florida from Punta Gorda, FL, United States to Islamorada, FL, United States

From route received two links

```
0: {linkId: "-91500228", mappedPosition: {latitude: 26.9336687, longitude: -82.0531188},…}
1: {linkId: "+897488196", mappedPosition: {latitude: 24.9598652, longitude: -80.5699824},…}
```

Then do tolls request

```
 https://tce.api.here.com/2/tollcost.json
    ?app_id=my_app_id
    &app_code=my_code
    &tollVehicleType=3
    &vehicleNumberAxles=2
    &emissionType=6
    &height=3.5m
    &vehicleWeight=10.0t
    &limitedWeight=10.0t
    &passengersCount=1
    &tiresCount=8
    &route=-91500228;897488196
    &detail=1
```

In response always receive:

```
{"errors":[],"warnings":[{"category":1,"context":"Old response format is deprecated, please use request parameter &rollup"}],"countries":[],"onError":false}
```

Tried different locations in usa, no matter what - always empty countries array

Please advice what I'm missing, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example:

https://tce.cit.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?jsonAttributes=41&waypoint0=26.13442,-81.68696&detail=1&waypoint1=26.08104,-80.36682&routelegattributes=li&routeattributes=gr&maneuverattributes=none&linkattributes=none,rt,fl&legattributes=none,li,sm&currency=EUR&departure=&tollVehicleType=3&emissionType=5&height=3.8m&vehicleWeight=11000&limitedWeight=11t&passengersCount=1&tiresCount=4&commercial=1&heightAbove1stAxle=1m&width=2.55&length=10&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:enabled&rollup=none,country;tollsys&app_id=yyy&app_code=xxx

In general is the parameter rollup missing in your request. This one need to be added in any case. Besides of that is the route you try to calculate quite far over islands with a truck with a specific size and weight. It is quite difficult to get an idea within the pure HTTPRest request. Maybe this demo page helps a bit for debugging such cases:

https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/route_with_tce

Comment: Im using your H.service.Platform by calling platform.getRoutingService(), and its sending request to https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json - which doesnt give toll cost prices, your url I didnt find in any service/platform from api - tce.cit.api.here.com, I assume its only raw call to that url?